# Delete from the current cursor position to a given line number in vi editor

Tags: vi, editing

How do I delete a block of text from the current cursor row to a given line number in vi?

For example:

```
 49 <j:set var="changeSet" value="${build.changeSet}" /> <----- delete from here (cursor position)
 50 <j:if test="${changeSet!=null}">
 51   <j:set var="hadChanges" value="false" />
 52   <TABLE width="100%">
 53     <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>CHANGES</B></TD></TR>
 54     <j:forEach var="cs" items="${changeSet.logs}" varStatus="loop">
 55       <j:set var="hadChanges" value="true" />
 56       <j:set var="aUser" value="${cs.hudsonUser}"/>
 57       <TR>
 58         <TD colspan="2" class="bg2">${spc}Revision <B>${cs.revision}</B> by
 59           <B><j:choose>
 60             <j:when test="${aUser!=null}">${aUser.displayName}: </j:when>
 61             <j:otherwise>${cs.user}: </j:otherwise>
 62           </j:choose></B>
 63           <B>(${cs.msgAnnotated})</B>                <----- to here (line 63)
 64          </TD>
 65       </TR>
 66       <j:forEach var="p" items="${cs.paths}">
 67         <TR>
 68           <TD width="10%">
```

In Vim I would usually use the visual selection mode for this, but I don't have Vim at my disposal on this server. It would also be quicker to specify a line number rather than counting how many lines are within the block in some cases.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/how-do-i-delete-a-large-block-of-text-without-counting-the-lines

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You could use something like `d63G` to delete from the current line until line 63.

Comment: Oooh, a solution in normal mode - even better!

Comment: To add to this, if you want to delete lines 45 through 64, you do :45,64d

Answer (score 121):

To delete from *a* to *b* use

```
:a,bd
```

from current to *b* use

```
:,bd
```

(where *a* and *b* in code are replaced by your numbers)

Comment: Excellent. I was able to do ":.,63d" to perform the deletion example above. Thanks borrible!

Answer (score 23):

Same as the accepted answer, but slightly faster to type:

`d63gg` deletes from the current line to line 63.

Answer (score 12):

Why count lines?  Go to the last line you want to delete and mark it by typing `ma` which "marks" it with identifier "a".  Then go up to the top line that you want to delete and type `d'a` for delete to mark "a".  Bam!

Comment: Doesn't work (vim 7.4.160, CentOS). Perhaps it needs some extension or special config.

Answer (score 7):

To delete a block of lines in Vi:

`n`: is *from* line number

`m`: is *to* line number

1. From current line until a given line number-

   `:,md`
2. from/to specific line numbers

   `:n,md`